# Delaunay triangulation in more than three dimensions

Tags: mesh, delaunaymesh

I need to have Mathematica do a [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) in any dimension. The best solution I have found so far uses `MeshRegions`.
Here is a (trivial) example:

```
o = {0, 0, 0};
a = {0, 0, 1};
b = {0, 1, 0};
c = {1, 0, 0};
oa = (o + a)/2;
ob = (o + b)/2;
oc = (o + c)/2;
ab = (a + b)/2;
ac = (a + c)/2;
bc = (b + c)/2;
m = DelaunayMesh[{o, a, b, c, oa, ob, oc, ab, ac, bc}, MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"}]
MeshCells[m, 3]
```

Which yields:
[image]
Which is pretty much what I want.

However, when doing the exact same thing in 4D:

```
o = {0, 0, 0, 0};
a = {0, 0, 0, 1};
b = {0, 0, 1, 0};
c = {0, 1, 0, 0};
d = {1, 0, 0, 0};
oa = (o + a)/2;
ob = (o + b)/2;
oc = (o + c)/2;
od = (o + d)/2;
ab = (a + b)/2;
ac = (a + c)/2;
ad = (a + d)/2;
bc = (b + c)/2;
bd = (b + d)/2;
cd = (c + d)/2;
m = DelaunayMesh[{o, a, b, c, d, oa, ob, oc, od, ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd}, MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"}];
MeshCells[m, 3]
```

It seems Mathematica doesn't even try to evaluate the expression:

```
Out:[] = MeshCells[ DelaunayMesh[{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 
0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 
0}, {1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 1/2}, {0, 1/2, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 
0, 1/2}, {0, 1/2, 1/2, 0}, {1/2, 0, 1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 0, 0}},  MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"}], 3]
```

I fear Mathematica has not implemented meshes in D>3. Does any one know of a way to do that?

Notes on what I have already tried:

- I know that there is a C++ package to do this, but I would rater only use Mathematica
- I would also rather not re-code Delaunay triangulation from scratch
- Ideally, there is a way (or an extension/package) that allows `MeshRegions` to work in any dimension.
- If anyone knows of a packages that would allow me to input coordinates of points (in a given dimension D) and get back a list of D+1 tuples that are the polytopes that make a Delaunay triangulation of my original set, that would be great!

Comment: Well, if there are C++ packages out there, then you could use LibraryLink to access them from within _Mathematica_. This requires some coding effort, but maybe that's what you have to do...

Comment: Indeed, it seems  `DelaunayMesh` does not work in equal to or greater  than four dimensions.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher yet, I know of these packages, I just wanted to avoid that... I'll keep loking for a while, but in the end, that's probably what I'll do. Thanks anyway :-)